# How query only level 1 and 2 user lists from table Laravel

Tags: laravel

I created referral link register syste
m.After that I need to make view blade form to show user lists that only from level 1 and 2.
Because I want to credit this users In referral system.

Level 1 bonus - %
Level 2 bonus - %
Etc.

Thanks

here codes

usercontroller

```
public function referral() {
  $user = User::find(1);

  return view('users.referral', compact('user'));
}

public function viewreferral() {
    $users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('users.viewreferral',compact('users'));
  }
```

[user table]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAogM.png

I use this in view but not work

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                  <th>Level</th>
                  <th>UserName</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Referred_by</th>
                  <th>Affiliate_id</th>
                  <th>Activation</th>
                  </thead>
             <tbody>

              @foreach($users as $singleUser)

                   <tr>
                  @if($singleUser->level === 1 || $singleUser->level === 2)
                    <td>{{$singleUser->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$singleUser->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$singleUser->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$singleUser->referred_by}}</td>
                    <td>{{$singleUser->affiliate_id}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{'/activate'}}">Activation</td>
                 @endif
                  </tr>

              @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

here myregistercontroller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
       $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');

            $user =  User::create([
                      'name' => $data['name'],
                      'email' => $data['email'],
                      'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                      'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
                      'referred_by'   => $referred_by,
                        ]);

                   return $user;
  }
```

Comment: can you show your database structure, controller code & views that you already have?

Comment: I edited my question with codes bro.plz check

Comment: didn't see any `level` column in your table

Comment: how can do that ,I need to add column level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your user migration add something like `user_level`. then you can iterate through your users like

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->level === 1)
        //do something
    @elseif($user->level === 2)
        //do something else
    @else
        //user does not have level
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: how can insert data into this user level .

Comment: That depends on how you want the levels to work. Do you want a user to gain a level for every referral?

Comment: Yes I want that exactly bro.You right

Comment: I edited in question by  registercontroller

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
@foreach($user as $singleUser)
 @if($singleUser->level === 1 || $singleUser->level === 2)
    {{ $singleUser->name }}
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I edited my question with codes bro.plz check